# Is there a way to write a function that would shift a sum of functions by some parameter?

Tags: r, function

I'm new to R and recently I've faced the following problem.

I have a function of x, `f(x)`, which is itself a sum of other functions of the same data, for example, `f(x) = 2 * f1(x) + 3 * f2(x)`. I want these functions to be shifted by some parameter a, leading to the expression `f(x - a) = 2 * f1(x - a) + 3 * f2(x - a)`. Later I have some iterative procedure and the parameter a doesn't remain the same all over the process, meaning that at the next step there should be `f(x - a - b) = 2 * f1(x - a - b) + 3 * f2(x - a - b)` and so on, that's why changing the argument of the function explicitly is not possible.

Thus, I have the following question: is there any way to write a function that, applied to the function `f(x)`, will lead to the result
`fun(f(x)) = 2 * f1(x - a) + 3 * f2(x - a)`?

If not, how should this problem be solved using R?

I've been thinking about loops and apply functions but didn't manage to overcome this issue. Also I haven't found anything similar to this problem in the Internet.

I really appreciate any help and will be glad to read your advice.

Comment: You could create a string in a loop and use eval(parse(x)) to create a new function

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. You seem to just be calling `f()` with `x-a`. Can you give examples of actual functions here? And some sort of example that we can be used for testing that gives a specific input and a desired output? It shouldn't be too hard to write a function that returns another function with some shifting going on.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for you answer! If I understand your question correctly, f1() and f2() are empirical distribution functions of data x already shifted by different parameters, which I want both to be shifted by a. I use f() as an expression of their sum. And writing 'a function that returns another function with some shifting going on' is exactly what I want to do

Comment: Then maybe something like `shiftf <- function(f, a) function(x) f(x-a)` would be what you want. You can get `newf <- shiftf(f, a)` and call `newf()`. This isn't easy to answer without specifics to test with, but that would be the general idea.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks! It seems to be what I need. However, could you explain how the code for shiftf should look like? 
As for specifics, x is a list of, say, 10 entries, so if `f(x) = f(c(1, 2, 3, ..., 10) )` by shifting it by 2 we should get `f(x-2) = f(c(-1, 0, 1, ..., 8) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function

```
f <- function(x) x
```

and you want a version that's shifted, you can write a shiftf function

```
shiftf <- function(f, a) function(x) f(x-a)
```

This is a function that takes a function and an offset, and returns an new function. You can use it like

```
fnew <- shiftf(f, 2)
```

and then you can call

```
x <- 1:10
f(x)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
fnew(x)
#  [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
shiftf(f, 2)(x)
#  [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I definitely have to study functions in R in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. if you have a data frame with all values you want to put into the various functions, you can pass a formula to the function lambda_shift and it will return the output. If you had the results from f() in column a, you could pass lamda_shift(.x,.y(a-b)) to get your results.  Column b contains shifting values.

```
require(purrr)
lamda_shift<-as_mapper(~mutate(.x,
                                output =  2*(!!enquo(.y))+3*(!!enquo(.y))
                              )
                       )

df <- data.frame(a=rep(1:1),b=rep(6:10))
lamda_shift(.x=df,.y=a-b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

This is probably correct, but as a beginner, I do not really understand what is happening here.

Comment: Totally understand. Here is a good starting point for some dplyr programming. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

Comment: Thank you! I think it will be very useful.